# Open/Closed Principle in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solid-principles

Let's say I have two different lists related to the same domain, like:

```
const [peopleList, setPeopleList] = useState([])
const [equipmentList, setEquipmentList] = useState([])
```

I'm defining only one handler to deal with the changes on those lists:

```
const handleListChange = (e, type) => {
  type === 'people' 
    ? setPeopleList(e.target.value)
    : setEquipmentList(e.target.value)
}
```

And passing it to different components:

```
<Component onChange={e => handleListChange(e, type)} />
```

I am not respecting the Open/Closed principle, and therefore if I have a third option I would have to change my handler to deal with the new option.

My question is: is there a better construction/best practice for those type of situations?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work? If so - when you need to add a third option, worry about it later. One question - are you always showing both lists or are you only ever showing one list?

Comment: It does work, I'm just trying to improve my construction. Both lists are displayed at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a single state:

```
const [state, setState] = useState({
  people: [],
  equipment: [],
  // ... etc
});
```

And use the `type` as a dynamic key in the handler:

```
const handleListChange = (e, type) => {
  setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    [type]: e.target.value;
  }));
};
```

This would leave the handler more generic/general.

I would curry the `type` parameter so you wouldn't need to proxy the event object through in an anonymous callback.

```
const handleListChange = type => e => {
  setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    [type]: e.target.value;
  }));
};

...

<Component onChange={handleListChange(type)} />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is an improvement for sure.